# Derivation of the inverse laplace transform

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I'm trying to derive the form of the inverse laplace transform and am having some difficulty.

I start with the definition which is the classical $\mathcal{L} (f(t))(s)  = \int_0^{\infty} e^{-st} f(t)dt $

From here i'm noting that this can be expanded as

$$ -\frac{1}{s}e^{-st}f(t)|_0^{\infty} -\frac{1}{s^2}e^{-st}f'(t)|_0^{\infty}-\frac{1}{s^3}e^{-st}f''(t)|_0^{\infty}...$$

via integration by parts.

Now this is a laurent series in $s$ which assuming sufficiently slow growing $f$ yields

$$ L(f) =  \frac{f(0)}{s} + \frac{f'(0)}{s^2}  + \frac{f''(0)}{s^3} \cdots $$

So recalling we have

$$ f(t) =  f(0) + f'(0)t + \frac{1}{2} f''(0)t^2  + \cdots $$

Perhaps there is some way I can now algebraically manipulate the above to get the bottom (but so far any such operator i come up with has been quite ugly).

So how to proceed?

Comment: Then the expansion doesn't hold

Comment: When one does not find one does not find an Inverse Laplace transform by using tables, one has to use complex variable integration with what is called a Bromwich contour. This is seldom done...

Comment: That's what I'm trying to derive

Comment: This is correct if $\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(t)}{e^{st}} = 0$  for all n-th derivatives of $f$

Comment: @JeanMarie i want to get a better grasp of the continuos realm, so i can port the procedure of deriving the inverse into a different operator setting (instead of integrals will be more exotic classes of operators [which share a lot of common properties with integrals!] ) so albeit an odd request, i need to get a very clear idea of how to derive an inverse to proceed.

Comment: I understand your point of view. But you could also start from the fact that the inverse "is" (with many quotes) \mathcal{L} (f(t))(s)  = \int_?^{?} e^{+st} f(t)dt with a $+$ sign instead of a $-$ sign in the exponent

Comment: Consider the bilateral Laplace transform. Prove that for any $a \in \mathbb{R}$ : $\mathcal{L}^{-1}[\mathcal{L}[e^{-at^2}](s)](u) = e^{-a u^2}$ and use that the Gaussians are dense in $C^1$ (this is the same proof we use for the [Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_inversion_theorem#Proof))

Comment: You want to find an operator that sends $\frac{1}{s^n} \to \frac{t^n}{n!}$...